# Prevent user from using keyboard shortcuts on Windows?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-registry, group-policy

Is there a way to prevent users from using keyboard shortcuts or to choose the ones that are ok to be used? I was looking for a GPO or a registry but I can't find anything...

Comment: That's a very, very bad idea. Shortcuts are important for some users and disabling them wouldn't solve your problem. You should disable the functionality you don't want to allow, not the shortcuts.

Comment: You can use `AutoHotKey` to disable most of windows shortcuts. [this](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm) can help.